# JWT Error using GoogleApi node client

Tags: node.js, api, calendar, google-api, jwt

I am currently getting the error:

```
{ [Error: Not Found]
code: 404
errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound', message: 'Not Found' } ] }k
```

When trying to use the calendar api using JWT. I am struggling to find this error message and how to debug this online. Please help! My code is the following:

```
jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  // Make an authorized request to list calendar files
  calendar.events.list({ 
    auth: jwtClient,
    calendarId: calendarId,
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 100,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime' 
  }, function(err, resp) {
    // handle err and response
    console.log("===============")
    console.log(err)
    console.log(resp)
  });
});
```

The call works when i authorize via auth.OAuth2...